# Counting the depth of a tree using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I've been trying to make a program that will take user input (an integer) and increment that integer for every level in a tree, using recursion:

**Edit**:
This is the `__init__` method for the class `set_depth` is in:

```
class BTNode(object):
    """A node in a binary tree."""

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        """(BTNode, int, BTNode, BTNode) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store value and have children left and right,
        as well as depth 0.
        """
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.depth = 0  # the depth of this node in a tree

    def set_depth(self, number_of_depth):
            #Set depth of root node to 0, then all of its children to 1, and so on
            child = BTNode(number_of_depth)

            if self.left is None and self.right is None:
                return self.depth
            else:
                if self.left is not None or self.right is not None:
                    self.depth += 1
                    self.set_depth(number_of_depth)
                child.left = child
```

I keep getting the maximum recursion depth error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to set the depth of each node in an existing tree:

```
class BTNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.depth = 0

    def set_depth(self, depth):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.set_depth(depth+1)
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.set_depth(depth+1)
        self.depth = depth
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the number_of_depth parameter (no increment...).
My guess is, that BTNode(number_of_depth) returns the same child instance in every recursion and so you're don't have a terminal condition.

Just a guess.
Try this:

```
def set_depth(self, number_of_depth):
    #Set depth of root node to 0, then all of its children to 1, and so on
    child = BTNode(number_of_depth)

    if self.left is None and self.right is None:
        return self.number_of_depth
    else:
        if self.left is not None or self.right is not None:
            self.number_of_depth += 1
            self.set_depth(number_of_depth)
        child.left = child
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added the `__init__` method, each instance of `BTNode` has an attribute `depth` that hold the current level each child is at.

Comment: Try to increment the number_of_depth of your version in each recursion.